# Memcached bug in PHP - binary protocol

Tags: php, memcached

I came across a bug using Memcached in PHP. Here's my piece of code:

```
<?php
$mc = new \Memcached();
$mc->setOption(\Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true);
$mc->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);

$mc->touch("key", time() + 600);
$touchResult = $mc->getResultCode();
$mc->set("key", 1, time() + 600);
$setResult = $mc->getResultCode();

echo "<pre>";
echo "Touch result: $touchResult\n";
echo "Set result: $setResult\n";
echo "</pre>";
```

When you run this for the first time, this is the output:

```
Touch result: 16
Set result: 0
```

And for the second time forth:

```
Touch result: 0
Set result: 5
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but this is a bug right? Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Here are the versions I use:

- **Ubuntu 12.04 64bit**
- **PHP 5.3.14**
- **memcached 2.1.0 (PECL module)**
- **libmemcached 1.0.8**
- **Memcached sever 1.4.13**

PS. If you wonder what the result codes mean, here they are:

```
0  RES_SUCCESS
5  RES_WRITE_FAILURE
16 RES_NOTFOUND
```

**[UPDATE]**

I played a little more with the code and found something even more interesting. This bug happens regardless of the `key` that `touch` and `set` are working on. As long as the `touch` operation returns `0` (which means it was successful) the `set` operation will fail.

**[UPDATE]**

I managed to produce some other errors as well. e.g. acquiring some `key` from server and then `add`ing some other will also lead to nasty problems (`RES_END` code). I believe all these problems are somehow related to binary protocol. It seems to me as if binary protocol's implementation is hardly near stable. Operations which can work without binary protocol will do just fine but once the protocol is set to binary, they will result in blocking problems.

Comment: The same happens to me. When I've switched to binary protocol in my project I started getting a lot of "write failure" errors. Do you have any news on the issue?

Comment: I've issued a bug on github. It's labeled as resolved but I'm not sure if it actually is. Perhaps you can follow it there: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/77

Answer (score 0):

All right.

In first time, you touch not existed key - result is RES_NOTFOUND. When you do set - you write value success - RES_SUCCESS.

In next time you touch existed key (you set it in first linch) and get result of operation RES_SUCCESS, next you try set value for existed key - result false. All right.

If you want change existing value you must use Memcached::replace() method instead of "set"

Comment: I believe `set` covers `replace`. Nevertheless, the same happens with `replace` (result code `5`).

Comment: Some sources said, that may be problem with too quickle access to Memcached server. For testing, try set sleep function between touch and set

Comment: Thanks for the advise but it didn't work. I inserted a `sleep(5);` between the two lines but still the same result.